# Unlocking Liquibase with H2 database with Spring Boot in local

Tags: spring-boot, h2, liquibase

I am working on a spring boot app in local with file based H2 database and liquibase for constructing database.

I was doing some change and the app got terminated suddenly causing the lock to be true in databasechangeloglock and the app is not getting up anymore since the lock is locked.

I already see multiple places that we have log mark lock as false in databasechangeloglock but while using the h2 i cannot access databasechangeloglock table since app itself is not getting up. In this situation, i need help in either finding alternate approach to unlock liquibase or an alternate way to access databasechangeloglock while app is not getting up.

Comment: just open your database with any h2 client h2console for example (that comes with h2 bundle). Even intellij can connect to h2 database. By "connecting" here I mean pointing database file on your disk, as h2 stores data as file (non memory variant obviously).

Comment: @Antoniossss Thanks. I later realized this. I connect H2 later on with cmd.

Answer (score 0):

I realized that i can connect H2 by cmd with the H2 Shell tool. Just for the reference for anyone else faces this issue, below are the steps to connect H2 by cmd and get Liquibase unlocked.

Step 1: Navigate to location in cmd where data is present. In H2, its data folder generally.

Step 2: run command

```
java -cp path/to/h2JarUsedInThatProject/h2-*.jar org.h2.tools.Shell -url jdbc:h2:file:/data/taskdb -user sa -password password"
Example: java -cp C:\Users\xxxxxx\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.h2database\h2\2.1.214\d5c2005c9e3279201e12d4776c948578b16bf8b2\h2-2.1.214.jar org.h2.tools.Shell -url "jdbc:h2:file:/data/taskdb" -user sa -password password
```

Step 3: sql terminal will get open. Run below three queries

```
select * from datbasechangeloglock
update DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK set locked = FALSE, LOCKGRANTED=null, LOCKEDBY=null;
exit
```

Application should get up.